# DataNucleus: Class ... for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports specification

Tags: spring, spring-roo, datanucleus

I have a problem, hopefully someone can give me some hints.

Environment:

- **maven** project with **two modules**
- one module is the '**model**', and has **DataNucleus 3.1**, **HSQLDB** and **Spring 3** dependencies. HSQLDB runs **embedded**, in memory, configured from spring applicationContext.xml
- the other module is the 'web' and has **GWT dependencies**

The application is built using some Spring Roo generated code as basis, later modified and extended.

The issue is that, when starting the app and trying to load the data, I receive the exception:

```
 Class Document for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports specification; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class Document for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports specification
```

The weirdest thing is that the sample roo-generated aplication used as basis, with exactly the same dependencies, but a different modularization works like a charm, without this symptom, so I am puzzled now...
Please also note that I tried to replace the 'Document' with the explicit qualification 'com.myvdm.server.domain.Document' in the query, with no positive result:

```
return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) FROM Document o", Long.class).getSingleResult();
```

Another thing, although it might not be relevant, on every request, this exception is thrown:

```
 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Unexpected exception on closing JPA EntityManager [INFO] java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is managed by a container (JEE) and so cannot be closed by calling the EM.close() method. Please read JPA2 spec 3.1.1 for the close() method.
```

The last exception is thrown by DataNucleus. It's also confusing, since I do not run in a Java EE container, but GWT development mode.

Here's the document entity:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Document {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private DocumentType type;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Field> fields;
}
```

The annotation @RooJpaActiveRecord adds EntityManager operations but these are declared in a separate file - ITD(inter-type declarations)

Any suggestions, please?
Thanks a lot in advance.

----------- EDIT --------------

```
privileged aspect Document_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord {

    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager Document.entityManager;

    public static final EntityManager Document.entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new Document().entityManager;
        if (em == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }

    public static long Document.countDocuments() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) FROM Document o", Long.class).getSingleResult();
    }

    public static List<Document> Document.findAllDocuments() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Document o", Document.class).getResultList();
    }

    public static Document Document.findDocument(Long id) {
        if (id == null) return null;
        return entityManager().find(Document.class, id);
    }

    public static List<Document> Document.findDocumentEntries(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Document o", Document.class).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Document.persist() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.persist(this);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Document.remove() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        if (this.entityManager.contains(this)) {
            this.entityManager.remove(this);
        } else {
            Document attached = Document.findDocument(this.id);
            this.entityManager.remove(attached);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Document.flush() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.flush();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Document.clear() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Document Document.merge() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        Document merged = this.entityManager.merge(this);
        this.entityManager.flush();
        return merged;
    }
}
```

@Entity declaration

```
privileged aspect Document_Roo_Jpa_Entity {

    declare @type: Document: @Entity;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long Document.id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer Document.version;

    public Long Document.getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void Document.setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer Document.getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void Document.setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may not run in a "container, but then there are 2 ways of creating an EMF and if Spring does it using the container creator then as far as DataNucleus knows you're in a container. The log obviously tells you more but then since you don't present real JPA model classes here but instead some Springified variant then that isn't what DataNucleus sees. Spring is known to incorrectly call em.close when it shouldn't, hence that reference to the JPA spec

Comment: I don't think I follow you my friend, why does DataNucleus not see the ITD's? Your answer is not very helpful, as I said, a roo-generated app works perfectly with the above-mentioned technical environment. The fact that I made some modifications (just related to maven modularization) should not break everything. And you are suggesting probably that I should stop using Spring? :) Can you suggest some alternatives then? I edited the initial response and added an ITD declaration. What do you mean by 'Springified'? These are AOP ITD's...

Comment: I said this is a Spring "entity" (not something you pass direct to a JPA implementation) consequently not of interest to me ... I want to know what your JPA implementation sees (since that is its input) ... where does that say "stop using Spring"? DataNucleus sees @Entity and I don't see any of those above. So how does Spring create an EMF? That is where you'll find your answer.

Comment: ok, sorry for that, there you go, I added another ITD...

Comment: ...and I'm researching a little bit about how Spring inits that EMF...

Comment: Oh another observation, I'm not very keen on using Spring, I am planning a migration on CDI actually, but for now I have to make it work with Spring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a fix for this problem.
As I posted earlier, using Spring's applicationContext.xml and persistence.xml files as basic configuration I could not make it work. I deleted persistence.xml and instead I used this configuration (please note the usage of packagesToScan property and passsing DataNucleus properties - and basically all the info that was traditionally inside persistence.xml):

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
      id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myvdm.server.domain"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="rdbms"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myvdm"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.ConnectionUserName" value="sa"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateTables" value="true"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateColumns" value="false"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateConstraints" value="false"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.validateTables" value="false"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.validateConstraints" value="false"/>
            <entry key="datanucleus.jpa.addClassTransformer" value="false"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

So this is the only way I could make it work, could this be a Spring bug?

And about that second (minor) issue, obviously the exception will be thrown since I am using Spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a Spring bug, it is simply a "Debug" level message.  To suppress that message, change the log level `<logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils"  additivity="false" level="error"/>`.

See my ORM demo here: https://github.com/gordonad/core-spring-demos/tree/master/demos/orms